# Зависимые select'ы

Tags: javascript, php, html, select

есть файл `table.php`. В нем весь html, в том числе 2 зловещих `select'a`. Если список в первом `select`'e постоянный, то второй `select` зависимый.

```
  <div class="dropdown">
    <form>
      <select id="regions">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Регион</option>
        <?php 
include "address.php";
region(); 
?>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown1">
    <form>
      <select id="street" name="nameselect">
      <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Адрес</option>
      <?php 
      //addressMDE(12);
        ?>

      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
```

В файле `address.php` , в функции `addressMDE($regionsMDE)` формируется список для второго `select`'a, где `$regionMDE` - значение первого `select`'a.

Получилось вывести список адресов на сайте(не в `select`'e), получилось вывести список адресов в `selecte` определённого региона(не завися от первого `select`'a).

Как сделать, что бы `select` формировался зависимо и без обновлений?

Comment: Сделай сначала с обновлениями. потому будешь учить яваскрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только при помощи ajax запросов. Суть такая, делаешь событие onchange на первый селект после срабатывания выполняешь функцию с ajax запросом где передаешь значение селекта 1 GET или POST методом на сервер и получаешь ответ в виде option и полученный ответ при помощи DOM подставляешь внутрь select.
Я новичок в этом, но недавно выполнял похожую задачу. Возможно совет выше Вам поможет.